# Add button to thyme leaf table

Tags: html, thymeleaf

Hello I hope you are all well,

I'm trying to figure out how to add a button next to a thymeleaf expression in my table, so that I do not have to create a new column for something that barely take up any space. I'm not sure whether or not this is doable tho.

My current HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div th:if=${!#lists.isEmpty(taskList)} class="taskTable">
        <table class="showTasks">
            <tr>
                <th>Task name</th>
                <th>Amount of Hours</th>
                <th>Amount of Employees</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>End date</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each="task : ${taskList}">
                <form action="deleteTask" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" th:value="${task.taskID}" name="test">
                    <td th:text="${task.taskName}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${task.taskHours}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${task.taskEmployees}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${task.startDate}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${task.endDate}"></td>
                    <td> <input type="image" src="delete.png"  alt="Submit" class="deleteTaskBtn"></td>
                </form>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd rather like the button being on the same column as my endDate column, but I can't seem to make both the end date it self appear and the delete button.

In my head I thought it'd be something like this:

```
<td th:text="${task.endDate}"> <input type="image" src="delete.png"  alt="Submit" class="deleteTaskBtn"> </td>
```

So that it would appear as: End Date X

But obviously that's not right. I kinda struggle with the thymeleaf syntax at some points. Maybe this is an easy fix, I really don't know.

It looks like this right now:
[image: Example of issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the answer to your question, the Thymeleaf implementation may look like the following ...

```
<td><span th:text="${task.endDate}"></span> <input type="image" src="delete.png"  alt="Submit" class="deleteTaskBtn"> </td>
```

But I would consider using CSS style for the last column in your table (see your original HTML posted) and limit the width of this column to a pre-defined size (say 20px or so). As simple as that.

Comment: Of course, that could be an option as well. Thanks a lot for your input! May you have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

use button instead of input
Add some Font Awesome Icons to Your Buttons

**example**

```
<a class="some class" title="Delete" href="" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
```

Comment: That doesn't help with letting me show the button as well as the thyme leaf code in the same column

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do but what I find the easiest is give a button class to a link as in following example. Since this class is a bootstrap's class so you need to have reference to bootstrap.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

   
 <a href="@Url.Action("Index")" class="btn btn-success"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left"></i>&nbsp;Delete</a>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your other answer suggestion, but I'm not sure whether or not you read the original post. I'm aware about buttons, but thats not the point. The point is I'm curios whether or not I'm able to display some thymeleaf data AND any kind of button in the same column in my table. Right now the thymeleaf data is being prioritized over anything else